# A strange day at the beach

Tags: cipher, story

You are enjoying a nice day the beach when suddenly you see a note and phone floating in a bottle marqued “FREE” and you wonder how they shoved the Iphone X+ in there. Then you realize that there is a free phone up for grabs. You race over the bottle and smash the glass on a rock. You turn on the phone, but all comes up is a strange message a box benath it for the answer:

Oww ellw oned ouy idd ti utb oury extn teps si ot ecoded hist utb eavel uto uvt. Ouy eedn ot ecoded het extn artp ithw hist trategys irstf. oy oy fkk yst ejksio jz ftotfg

On the note it reads “If you manage to decode this puzzle, the error message will go away and you will have a new phone, to sell or to keep.”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After taking the last step Omega Krypton used,

> I took *yo yo kfk tys oejksi zj gftotf* and placed it in to quipquip cipher solver to get "**ha ha wow the answer is potato**".

So,

> The code is potato

Comment: Darn quip quip there was a cipher

Comment: For what it's worth, the cipher is a rot13(Pnrfne fuvsg ol avar cynprf gung yrnirf gur yrggref ghi vagnpg, nf jnf qrfpevorq va gur svefg cneg. V qba'g xabj jurer gur avar pbzrf sebz, ohg ghi ner gur yrggref ba n cubarf'f rvtug xrl.)

Answer (score 5):

Partial

First half of message:

> Oww ellw oned ouy idd ti utb oury extn teps si ot ecoded hist utb eavel uto uvt. Ouy eedn ot ecoded het extn artp ithw hist trategys irstf.

Decoded Message

> Wow well done you did it but your next step is to decode this but leave out tuv. You need to decode the next part with this strategy first.

Method:

> Anagram each word: Put the last letter of the encrpyted phrase to the front.

Second half of message:

> oy oy fkk yst ejksio jz ftotfg

Step 1:

> use the same method used in first part

result:

> yo yo kfk tys oejksi zj gftotf

Comment: Good job find the rule for getting those anagrams

Comment: oops typo I study french too much lol also that was fast I will add a hint in 20 hours. I fixed my typo in the riddle

Comment: So how did they get the phone inside the bottle? Is that a seperate puzzle :)?